# Is it possible to write equations in google docs (like integrals or limits of functions) from google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to write equations in google-docs but I would like to do it from google apps scripts. 
The reason I want this is because I have to do some reports and they involve doing the same calculations a bunch of times over a table of data, and yes, I have to write the same questions every time. 
So I would like to automate this, one of the requierements is that the final report has to be written in google docs, so latex is not an option.

Comment: [Yes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/equation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me where to find information about how to do this? I've exhausted all the options I could find, but I still dont know how to do it. The google apps scritps page, describes all the methods but doesn't say how write a fraction or anything specific. So I would really preciate any help you can give me.

Comment: See [structure of a document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs#structure_of_a_document) -- as equations can't be created from scratch in apps script currently, you will need to [copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#copy()) the calculation you have throughout your report.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the free add on called [Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076?utm_source=tex_stackoverflow_183358). It replaces all the text between $$ signs with high-quality images of the equation.

Basically your tag becomes the delimiters, like $$55 + \sqrt{5}$$ and renders all or one of the equations. If you mess up, you can always undo one or all the equations.